# React - integrate custom Bootstrap theme

Tags: reactjs

I've been trying for couple days to integrate a poor `Bootstrap` theme template in a `React` app with no success.

So, I've created a new application in my folder. All good. Installed all the packages required by the theme and upgraded to the latest version. All good.

[image]

Now, let's customize the `App.js` component in React with some custom code:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <section className="slice slice-lg delimiter-top delimiter-bottom">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row mb-6 justify-content-center text-center">
            <div className="col-lg-8 col-md-10">
              <span className="badge badge-primary badge-pill">
                What we do
              </span>
              <h3 className="mt-4">Leading digital agency for <span className="text-warning typed" id="type-example-1" data-type-this="business, modern, dedicated"></span> solutions</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="row row-grid">
            <div className="col-md-4">
              <div className="pb-4">
                <div className="icon">
                  <img alt="Image placeholder" src="../../assets/img/svg/icons/Apps.svg" className="svg-inject img-fluid" />
                </div>
              </div>
              <h5>Designed for developers</h5>
              <p className="text-muted mb-0">Quick contains components and pages that are built to be customized and used in any combination.</p>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-4">
              <div className="pb-4">
                <div className="icon">
                  <img alt="Image placeholder" src="../../assets/img/svg/icons/Ballance.svg" className="svg-inject img-fluid" />
                </div>
              </div>
              <h5>Responsive and scalable</h5>
              <p className="text-muted mb-0">Scalable and easy to maintain, Quick enables consistency while developing new features and pages.</p>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-4">
              <div className="pb-4">
                <div className="icon">
                  <img alt="Image placeholder" src="../../assets/img/svg/icons/Book.svg" className="svg-inject img-fluid" />
                </div>
              </div>
              <h5 className="">Very well documented</h5>
              <p className="text-muted mb-0">No matter you are a developer or new to web design, you will find our theme very easy to customize with an intuitive code.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Now, let's import everything we need from the custom theme in `index.js`:

```
...

import './assets/css/quick-website.css';
import './assets/js/quick-website.js';
import './assets/libs/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css';
import './assets/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js';

...
```

However, when I import the core `JS` (quick-website.js) file of the time, I get this types of errors:

1. From `quick-website.js`

[image]

2. From 'jquery.min.js`

[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: Looks like you might need to import jquery somewhere? What file are all the errors coming from?

Comment: @JBrown - forgot to include it in here but I'm importing it. I've edited the post. Those errors that starts with `expected an assignment...` are coming from `jquery.min.js` and the others are coming from `quick-website.js`.

Comment: Why are you storing `jquery.min.js` in assets?  I could be wrong but I think it's much better practice to run `npm install jquery` and then `import $ from 'jquery'` in each file where you need it. This might fix your issue.

Comment: Because I used `gulp` to compress all the files and used my `assets` as source directory.

Comment: I would try my suggestion above. It's more in line with the "React" way of doing things. All of your errors above look like they are occurring because you are not importing the needed modules in `quick-website.js`

Comment: @JBrown - it did worked, thanks. But some animated text that uses `typed.js` it doesn't. Do you have a tip on this too? 

Comment: Maybe post another question with more details about the `typed.js` issue. Glad the other part is working now though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than importing `jquery.min.js` from assets, you should use npm to install the jquery package and then import relevant modules in the files where you need them. This is a more "react" way of doing things and it's much easier to update dependencies from the command line.

1. Run `npm install jquery` from the command line
2. Now, just import modules where you need them (in this case, `quick-website.js`):

```
import $ from 'jquery'
```

In general, if you see the error `'Something' is not defined`, checking if you have imported the module is a good place to start.